# Can I append a string to an optional parameter while calling said function?

Tags: ruby

For example, if I have a function as follows

```
def test(two: 'foo')
  puts two
end
```

If I call it as `test`, I should get the output `foo`.

But if I want the output to be `foobar`, can I somehow call the function like `test(two + 'bar')`?

Comment: No; `two` is the parameter *in* `test` and has no meaning outside of the function (unless it's declared somewhere else, obviously). What's the actual goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `test` like this:

```
def test(two: 'foo', other: '')
  puts two + other
end
```

Calling `test` would have the same effect as your function, but calling `test(other: 'bar')` would give you the desired output:

```
test
#-> 'food'
test(other: 'bar')
#-> 'foobar'
```

You could also do this

```
def test(two: '')
  puts 'foo' + two
end
```

Then you could do this(closer to your attempt):

```
test(two: 'bar')
#-> 'foobar'
```

But you can't change the variables inside the method from the outside by just calling them by their name in the parameters.